# Expected value exponential distribution

Tags: probability

Let $\eta$ follow a exponential distribution.

I calculated:

\begin{align}
E[( 1+\eta)^k]&=E[\sum_{i=0}^{k} C_{k}^{i} \eta^i]\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k} C_{k}^{i}E[ \eta^i]\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k} C_{k}^{i}\frac{i!}{\lambda^i} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k} \frac{k!}{(k-i)!}\lambda^{-i}
\end{align}

But with lambda=6.66,k=19, this expected value is huge (several thousands) whereas a simple simulation in spreadsheet says it should rather be close to 14.

Is it the formula or the calculation that is wrong?

Comment: Curious to see the simulations leading to an expectation close to $14$ since already $kE(\eta^{k-1})\gt183$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the simple *Mathematica* code

```
F[t_,k_,n_] := Mean[(1+RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[t],10^n])^k]
Table[F[6.66,19,7],{20}]
G[t_,k_] := Sum[k!/(k-i)! t^(-i), {i,0,k}]
G[6.66,19]
```

We can see that the simulation results of $20$ trials of $10^7$ simulations each gives reasonable results compared to the expectation `G[6.66,19] = 21452.4`.

Comment: That's what I calculated indeed. I need to seriously review my simulation... It still feel a bit weird, because this big amount means, on "average", $\eta$ is 0.7, as $(1.7)^{19}=23K$. But $\eta$ mean is 0.15 and $1.15^{19}=14$...

Comment: I created a follow up question at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961085/wrong-simulation

Comment: Based on your above comment, I should let you know that $$\mathrm{E}[(1+\eta)^k] \ne (1+\mathrm{E}[\eta])^k.$$

Comment: When you do the simulation, you must do the following steps in order:  (1) generate $n$ random variates from the distribution of $\eta$.  (2) to each generated number, add 1.  (3) Raise each of the numbers to the $k^{\rm th}$ power.  (4) Add up all the values obtained in step 3.  (5) Divide by $n$.  If you do any of these steps in the wrong order, you will not get a correct result.

Comment: Heropup you saved me! The formula is right, but in my simu I was doing $\prod_{k=0}^{19}(1+\eta_k)$ whose expected value is $(1+E[\eta])^{19}$ (independence)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your calculation. Something is very wrong with your simulation.